# XCode 7.2.1 OpenGL Profiler: See Framebuffer contents

Tags: xcode, opengl, osx-yosemite, shadow-mapping

I'm currently attempting to use the OpenGL Profiler tool for XCode 7.2.1 to debug a non-functioning shadow map for an C/C++ OpenGL Application. As of yet, I can't seem to locate a feature that allows me to see the contents of a buffer (frame buffer or otherwise). Is there such a feature, or am I wasting my time trying to find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I didn't look hard enough before asking. oops

[image: herp-derp I found it immediately after asking]